# Laravel error debug page not loading correctly

Tags: php, laravel, debugging, heroku

I am trying to deploy a Laravel app to Heroku with Heroku Postgress. When I deploy however, error debug pages do not seem to load any CSS or JS, making it almost impossible to extract the info I need from the error page effectively. My browser dev tool only shows an error such as

**Firefox**

> Loading failed for the <script> with source “blob:https://...

**Chrome**

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

The network tool also tells me the only data coming is the HTML from the 500 response in this case.

I have made sure APP_DEBUG is true, APP_ENV is set to development and other essential variables are set. The error page looks fine when running locally and the app works fine when deployed other than the errors I need the debug page for to begin with.

here is the Procfile:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/
```

The console (censored and not including the trace from the error causing the page to be displayed in the first place):

```
2020-08-12T09:10:18.108148+00:00 app[web.1]: xxx - - [12/Aug/2020:09:10:17 +0000] "GET /xxx/1/xxx/create HTTP/1.1" 500 973197 "https://xxx.herokuapp.com/xxx/1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0
2020-08-12T09:10:18.401914+00:00 app[web.1]: xxx - - [12/Aug/2020:09:10:18 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have misconfigured the Procfile and that is causing 500 error.

Attach the Procfile and the error from the console so that we could understand it more.

Comment: Good point, I've edited the question but I haven't pasted the entire output as most of it is about the error causing the page to be displayed in the first place